# Предлагаю объединить метки "названия", "название", "названий"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Предлагаю объединить метки “названия", "название", “названий”. Мы отдаем предпочтение множественному числу. Тогда пусть метка “названия” будет главной, а “название” и "названий" – синонимами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метки объединены, синонимы созданы.

Спасибо за помощь!